# How do I separate author avatars and comments in 3.4.2?

Tags: comments

I see plenty of tutorials for much older versions of WP online, but cannot find one for 3.4.2 to separate comment content and the author's avatar/gravatar.

I'm seeking a code that separates the actual comments content from the gravatar **and does so in the simplest way possible**, I'd rather not update comments.php every time there's an update to the WP core.  Is there a simple way to do this with wp_list_comments?  I'm doing this for design purposes.

This is how I currently call avatars:

```
<?php wp_list_comments('avatar_size=60'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is what I've done.  If anybody has a better idea I will leave the answer open for a few hours and choose it!

```
<?php if($comments) : ?>  
    <ol>  
    <?php foreach($comments as $comment) : ?>  
        <li id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">  
            <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>  
                <p>Your comment is awaiting approval</p>  
            <?php endif; ?>
<cite class="fn"><?php comment_author_link(); ?> on <?php comment_date(); ?> at <?php comment_time(); ?></cite>  
            <?php comment_text(); ?>  

        </li>  
    <?php endforeach; ?>  
    </ol>  
<?php else : ?>  
    <p>No comments yet</p>  
<?php endif; ?>
```